# how to unit test a linked list using JUnit

Tags: java, junit, tdd

I'm a big fan of TDD and I usually write test cases for my university assignments before I write the code. So here's the interface of my assignment:

```
public interface SinglyLinkedList<E> {
    public void insertFirst(E e);
    public void insertAfter(E e, int index);
    public void removeFirst();
    public void remove(int index);
    public void removeAll();
    public E getFirst();
    public E get(int index);
    public int size();
    public String toString();
}
```

I wrote the whole testcase but it feels like I wrote bad test code. I can't find a way to write my test methods atomic. I.g. I can't a way to test remove() without using size(). Or I can't find a way to test insertFirst() without calling get() after.
As far as i know there is no way to mark testmethods dependencies right? Is there a way I can use mocking that solves the issue?
Or how would you approach this issue?

Comment: I see nothing wrong in using size() in a method testing remove(): part of the contract of remove() is that it MUST decrement the size if the object to remove is in the list, so it's perfectly natural to check that the size is correct after calling remove().

Comment: Note that a full TDD approach would start smaller, not writing the whole interface without testing. That way you can build up and not worry about methods using other methods as they are already tested and working.

Comment: The whole point of information hiding is to restrict a class to the public interface. Tests can only ascertain that this interface *collectively* reflects a correct, consistent state of the object. The task of writing tests is to find a (minimum) set of calls that do this, in various constellations, centering around the individual methods that are the "targets" of your test cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The units in unit testing don't have to be individual methods. It's more useful to think in terms of [contracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). A contract can be that given certain parameters a function should return a certain value, but often they are more complicated.

For example, there could be a contract that says that after calling `insertFirst`:

- `getFirst` returns the object you inserted
- `size` returns the old size plus one
- the output of `toString` includes the object inserted

These would be called postconditions of the contract. Contracts may also have preconditions: for example if the list is empty then `remove` should throw an exception.

When the contract requires interaction with an external entity, mock objects become useful. That is not the case here.

Comment: Hey Joni thank you for you answer that makes sense. Can you reference me to a book where I can find more information about this contract concept? I ordered pragmatic unit testing in java with junit. Do you think I will be able to find the details in there?

Comment: "The Pragmatic Programmer" has a chapter on design by contract. It's a pretty good book, one of my favorites